# get video from youtube with timestamp by word

Tags: javascript

I need to display an iframe page with a video on request for a certain word with a time stamp where this word is reproduced

I'm still able to find a video by keyword but without a time stamp

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We cannot write your code for you, please give us what you've tried so far and we can try to help you find out why it's not working. We can't just write whole files of code for you, though. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the YouTube API to search for videos based on keywords, retrieve the video ID and then use the API to retrieve the transcript of the video.then search the transcript for the desired word and retrieve the time stamp associated with that word